# Azure Search on text files

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Trying to setup Azure Search on blob container that has text files.

I have created a storage account and I'm using the Azure Data Lake gen2 stored in the blob container. I have one file as I'm testing the azure search. I have created the index, datasource and when I try to create the indexer I get

```
{"error":{"code":"","message":"Error with data source: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.  Please adjust your data source definition in order to proceed."}}
```

My file has no headers, contains 16 columns, and is pipe delimited 
so here is what I have tried for index

```
{
    "name" : "test-index",
    "fields": [
        { "name": "id", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": false },
        {"name":"TransactionId", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": true },
        {"name":"TransactionEventId", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": true },
        {"name":"EventTypeId", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": true },
        {"name":"EventSourceId", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": true },
        {"name":"SourceUserId", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": true },
        {"name":"SourceRecordId", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": true },
        {"name":"SourceDetails", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": true },
        {"name":"UserGlobalId", "type": "Edm.Int32", "key": false, "searchable": false },
        {"name":"CallDistributorKey", "type": "Edm.Int32", "key": false, "searchable": false },
        {"name":"CreatedDateTime", "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset", "key": false, "searchable": false },
        {"name":"AccountId", "type": "Edm.Int32", "key": false, "searchable": false },
        {"name":"LobId", "type": "Edm.Int32", "key": false, "searchable": false },
        {"name":"StartEvent", "type": "Edm.Int32", "key": false, "searchable": false },
        {"name":"EndEvent", "type": "Edm.Int32", "key": false, "searchable": false },
        {"name":"OnCall", "type": "Edm.Int32", "key": false, "searchable": false },
        {"name":"PresenceEventId", "type": "Edm.Int32", "key": false, "searchable": false },
        {"name":"EventProcessedUtcTime", "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset", "key": false, "searchable": false }
    ]
}


---also tried something much simpler
 "fields": [
        { "name": "id", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": false },
        { "name": "content", "type": "Edm.String",  "key":false, "retrievable": false , "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable":false, "searchable": true}
    ]

--datasource 
{
"name" : "test-ds", 
"type" : "azureblob", 
"credentials" : { "connectionString" :"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=......;AccountKey=..." }, 
"container" : { "name" : "test" }
}

--indexer
{   
  "name" : "test-indexer",  
  "dataSourceName" : "test-ds",
  "targetIndexName" : "test-index"
}

---get error 
{"error":{"code":"","message":"Error with data source: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.  Please adjust your data source definition in order to proceed."}}

--tried this indexer create as well
{   
  "name" : "test-indexer",  
  "dataSourceName" : "test-ds",
  "targetIndexName" : "test-index",
   "parameters" : { "configuration" : { "parsingMode" : "delimitedText", "delimitedTextDelimiter" : "|" , "delimitedTextHeaders" : "TransactionId
TransactionEventId,EventTypeId,EventSourceId,SourceUserIdSourceRecordId,
SourceDetails,UserGlobalId,CallDistributorKey,CreatedDateTime,AccountId,
LobId,StartEvent,EndEvent,OnCall,PresenceEventId,EventProcessedUtcTime" } }
}

---get error 
{"error":{"code":"","message":"Error with data source: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.  Please adjust your data source definition in order to proceed."}}
```

Any pointers would be great....

Answer (score 1):

This is an [existing issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-known-issues) of API interoperability between Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 and Blob Storage.

Azure Search uses Blob Storage APIs and these APIs are currently not compatible with hierarchical namespaces. You can disable the hierarchical namespaces feature to enable Azure Search indexing, but you'll lose some Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 [specific features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json#key-features-of-data-lake-storage-gen2).

Comment: In order to turn off the hierarchical namespaces I need to recreate the storage account. Ok, I can recreate as I'm testing Azure Search on the Data Lake Gen2. But once I re-created the storage acccount as Account Type = StorageV2 (general purpose v2) and go to create a container or services. I don't see "Data Lake Gen2 file systems" but I see the "Blobs". So does that mean my new storage account is not a Data Lake gen2 storage because I chose disable on the hierarchical setting?

Comment: So I want to be able to use Azure Search on the Data Lake Gen2? I know I can use Azure Search on blobs (storage accounts with blobs services or containers). 

Can Azure search be used on Data Lake Gen2?

Comment: Azure Search currently doesn't support Data Lake data sources. You can vote for the feature for [ADLS](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/15336090-add-support-for-using-azure-data-lake-with-blob-in) and [Gen2](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/35340688-implement-data-lake-gen2-search-indexer).

Selecting Account Type = StorageV2 will mean that you're using "plain Blob storage". Are there any particular ADLS Gen2 features you need?